# How to update a Flatpak application that was installed directly from a `.flatpak` file?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade, software-updates, github, flatpak

Updating a Flatpak application that was installed from a repository such as [Flathub](https://flathub.org) is as easy as issuing the command `flatpak update package_name`.  Updating a Flatpak application that was installed from a tool like Linux Mint's Software Manager is as simple as running Linux Mint's Update Manager.

Is the same `flatpak update package_name` command used to update a Flatpak application that was installed directly from a downloaded `.flatpak` file?  Or is a different command required?

As an example, let's use NAPS2, which is not currently available on Flathub or via Linux Mint's Software Manager.

To install the Flatpak version of it, one downloads `naps2-x.y.z-linux-[architecture].flatpak` from [GitHub](https://github.com/cyanfish/naps2/releases) or [SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/naps2/files/) and issues the command:

```
flatpak install naps2-x.y.z-linux-[architecture].flatpak
```

When a new version of the Flatpak is made available (via direct download from the author), what command is used to update it?

Answers appropriate for any Linux distro are welcome and appreciated.  Answers compatible with Mint 21.3 and Flatpak 1.12.7-1 are even better.

Comment: @muru No. I tend not to run commands unless I am relatively sure I am running the correct command.

Comment: From [the Ubuntu manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/noble/en/man1/flatpak-install.1.html): "Note that flatpak allows to have multiple branches of an application and runtimes
       installed and used at the same time. However, only one version of an application can be
       current, meaning its exported files (for instance desktop files and icons) are visible to
       the host. The last installed version is made current by default, but this can manually
       changed with flatpak make-current." Does your system's manpage have an equivalent paragraph?

Comment: @muru No, it does not.

Comment: The [1.12.7 manpage in Ubuntu](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/flatpak-install.1.html) has the same paragraph, so I guess this is just one of those differences between Linux Mint and Ubuntu.

Comment: @muru I just set up a Min 21.3 container because I couldn't believe they would remove something from a man page. It's there, contrary to what OP says; also, `apt info flatpak` does say the APT-Source is `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe`, so it's the unmodified Ubuntu package. I think they just might have mistyped the name of the man page when copying it from your link, or something.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Thanks for checking on that.  I was referencing the `flatpak` command, so I checked the `man` page for that command.  It doesn't have that paragraph.  After reading your comment, I double-checked, and it definitely doesn't have it.  But looking again at muru's link, they were linking to the `man` page for `flatpak-install`, which *does* have that paragraph.  Anyways, I'm still not clear on the answer to my question... does that mean the older Flatpak needs to be uninstalled, and the new Flatpak installed?  Or is an update mechanism available?

Comment: @muru Added details to question per your request.